# Running Multiple Gpus in theano jupyter notebooks, implementing theano.gpyarray.use

Tags: gpu, keras, theano-cuda

I have a linux system with three gpus.  I am using keras with theano to run cnn's,  In the past when I was using Theano 8.+ , I was able to assign a particular gpu to jupyter notebook window using the following:

import theano.sandbox.cuda
theano.sandbox.cuda.use("gpu2")

This allowed me to run three versions of the same cnn model using different hyper-parameters.

I very recently updated both keras (to 2.0) and theano ( to 0.9).  This required me to setup the gpuarray backend.

Running just one jupyter notebook with a model works fine.  gpu1 is selected by theano.   However when I startup a second notebook with the same model, theano tries to use the gpu assigned to the first notebook, causing a memory usage problem and ultimately causing the cnn model to run on the cpu rather than using one of the available two remaining gpus.

Is there a way to select the gpu that I wish the run on each jupyter notebook in theano 0.9 as I was able in theano 8.+